# Удаление элемента из List из другого потока

Tags: java

Можно ли как-то удалить элемент из ArrayList из другого потока?

Comment: Можно, но это опасно, например, если код в одном потоке хочет читать элемент, а в другом потоке хочет удалить одновременно. Можно использовать [Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Пример:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeleteFromList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Добавляем в потоке "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

        arrayList.add("foo");
        arrayList.add("bar");
        System.out.println(arrayList);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Удаляем в потоке "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                arrayList.remove("foo");
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println(arrayList);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Добавляем в потоке main
[foo, bar]
Удаляем в потоке Thread-0
[bar]
```

Код потокобезопасный, гарантировано работает.

Comment: Но сам по себе же `ArrayList` не потокобезопасный. И если добавление/удаление будут происходить одновременно, корректность не гарантируется.

Comment: @andreycha, про «одновременно» ничего в вопросе не было.